# pointcloud_to_laserscan package not working in ROS indigo

Tags: kinect, laserscan, ros-indigo, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pointcloud_to_laserscan package is not working properly in ROS Indigo. The Indigo build is done recently and seems to contain some error. As required by the node I have published the pointcloud data from Kinect in PointCloud2 format in /cloud_in topic. But the laserscan data that must be produced and published by Kinect in /scan topic seems erroneous. It returns an array full of 'Inf'. Please fix the error.

My code for publishing in /cloud_in is as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib
import rospy
import geometry_msgs.msg
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2

def callback(data):
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/cloud_in', PointCloud2,queue_size=10)
    pub.publish(data)

def pcl_2D():
    rospy.init_node('pcl_2D', anonymous=True)
    global listener 
    rospy.Subscriber("/camera/depth/points", PointCloud2, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__=='__main__':
    pcl_2D()
```

I have attached the rosbag which contains the data in topics `/cloud_in` `/rosout` and erroneous `/scan`. Each topics have 10 msgs published. I have compressed the bag using rosbag compress . Please use `rosbag decompress 2015-02-07-02-09-32.bag` before starting analyse.

Attachment link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7uPJVMkbpRKMEFWR3FzMDVMQ1U/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202202/pointcloud_to_laserscan-package-not-working-in-ros-indigo/) by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2015-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-02-01**:
You don't provide enough information to reproduce this problem; which makes it impossible to fix. At the very least, please provide the parameters that you're using for the pointcloud to lasterscan node, and a bag file of the pointcloud and tf data that you're feeding into it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-02-07**:
Posting the same question on ROS Answers and as a bug is considered poor etiquette. If you have a question, please ask it on ROS answers, and only report it as a bug if the answers suggest that it is actually a bug.

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-02-07**:
ya okay @ahendrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Continued here https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/73

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0